# Convert .png image to .gif image

Tags: image, png, gif

In my project, I have so many .png images. They are working properly in Firefox but when I run my project on Internet Explorer, i get white background in that images. I have used some Image converters but they are also not giving the proper result. After converting, the resolution gets changed.

So can any one suggest me some good Converter that will not change the resolution of image and will also convert the .png images to .gif images?

Comment: You have to know that gif only has binary transparency. You can't have *smooth borders* or *semi-transparent parts* in your image. Also ie 7 and up should handle PNG just fine

Comment: Is that on IE6? Sounds like problems with alpha transparency to me. There are workaround for that problem that let you keep your images as PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net)?
It has the ability to convert to several formats.

But keep in mind that the gif color palette is way smaller than PNG. Gif images can have up to 256 colors.

Which version of IE are you using? I thought that IE7 and 8 (8 for sure) support png images with transparency.

Comment: Ya i am using IE6. I don't have IE7. May be that's why i am getting the problem. Thanks for answering. And after trying Paint.NET, I will let you know if it works.

Comment: You really should use a PNG fix like the one here http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/ so that you have nice images for modern users and backwards support for legacy users.  GIFs use a limited palette and will look terrible compared to PNG even without transparency/alpha channels.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the most annoying bugs in IE6 - it doesn't support transparent PNGs.

Note that if you convert your PNG files to GIF images, they are likely to look uglier, as GIF files can only have 256 colors and do not support alpha-transparency.

IE6 features an AlphaImageLoader filter that can be used to render transparent PNGs correctly; this is a much better solution than converting to GIF.  (Unless you need transparent repeating backgrounds)
See [here](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6).